# Why can't I create a private static const void?

Tags: c#, .net

We just shifted from VB to C# and I am having some troubles..!

Why can't I create a private static const void??

why is it not working?

```
 private static const void MyVoid(void void)
 { 
   try
   {
      this.void void = new void(void + void);
      return this.void;
   }
   catch (void)
   {
      Response.Write(void);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Not my question sir, just edited it :)

Answer (score 6):

C# doesn't let you declare a method to be `const` whatever its return type is, so your method declaration is incorrect.

You can't catch `void` either - you can only catch exception types.

Ditto void parameters etc.

Why do you think you need this?

Answer (score 2):

`void` is the return type of **"there is no return type"**. It is not a type in itself (as in `int`, `bool` etc.), but rather specifies it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

it's because void is actually nothingness :) If you want to send nothing to methods. Do it
MyVoid()

The same is for other lines in your method

Answer (score 1):

void is a reserved keyword for "return nothing"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yah0tteb.aspx

here is the list of all reserved keywords 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx

think of Void like a Sub for C#

In C# we only have methods - which return something (VB Functions) or return nothing ie void (VB Sub)